# How to use DigiDoc C++ library with Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-xe2

I got http://www.id.ee/index.php?id=36484 I want to use it in Delphi. There is `demo-exe`. I opened it using Dependency walker and I see it uses digidocpp.dll I see `void digidoc::initialize(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)`
How do I call it in Delphi?

Comment: Apparently they used to distribute a COM and straight C version of this library.  Even if those were "deprecated" by them, if they are still functional, I'd select them over writing my own COM wrapper around their C++ version or creating my own procedural (C-like) wrapper around their C++ API, which presumably uses C++ std::string types.

Answer (score 2):

The function you refer to uses STL classes and so can only be accessed from C++ code. You will need to write a C++ adapter DLL and consume that from Delphi. The adapter consumes the C++ interface on one side, and presents an interface accessible to Delphi on the other. For instance you might expose COM compatible interfaces.

You will also need the documentation and SDK for the C++ library.

Comment: Such proxy library should use the same STL version as the original library. Otherwise it most likely fail on the first std::string destruction.

Comment: Yes. Presumably that is stated in the library's documentation.

Comment: Also, take a look at my article on using C++ classes from Delphi. The wrapper will have to hide away the STL classes, but otherwise, it is similat to [what I describe here](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html). You can use the COM wrapper approach, or the flattening approach.